# cannot cast String type to Object in java?

Tags: java

Can I cast Object type to String?

eg: a method `getResponse()` returns `Object` type of class `Request`.

```
 String s1=(String)req.getResponse();
```

Comment: No.. you can call `toString()` on it.. Which doesn't make much sense either (provided you've not overridden it.).

Comment: why do you need to cast it to String?

Comment: Or use `String.valueOf(req.getResponse())`

Comment: It has to be an `instance of` type `String` if you want to do that. All Objects are not Strings.

Comment: its downcasting i think

Comment: class A extends B {} 
    class B {} 
    class C {}

 A is B and Object, B is Object but it is not A, C is neither B nor A

Comment: what r u talking Object class and String class r having parent-child relationship

Comment: this is not an irrelavant topic i think this is the topic which u guys don't know  In java Downcasting is possible I want to know how we achieve it

Answer (score 1):

java cannot magically cast one object to any another object unless they have parent child relationship.

casts won't work in that way.

All `String`'s are `Object`'s. But not all `Object`'s are `String`'s.

---

**Edit to comment**(*u mean down casting is not possible in java*):

No. I didn't mean that. Down casting  is possible in the cases like

```
Object obj = getThat();
String s = (String) obj;
```

Possible, if you see. The above code executes fine if `getThat()` method returns a `String`. Otherwise a `Exception`.
Same rule applies to `getResponse()`  method too.

Comment: u mean downcasting is not possible in java

Comment: @user3530829 edited my post a  bit.

Comment: Thank u.... but its not working

Comment: @user3530829 What do you mean by not working >??? check this out  http://ideone.com/ycxH20 and this http://ideone.com/WK3x2J

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if Request is also a subclass of String (which is probably isn't in your case). What you can do though is this:

```
String s1=req.getResponse().toString();
```

Comment: or if it is a primitive type: `String.valueOf(req.getResponse());`

Answer (score 0):

if the getResponse() returns String object but in reference of type Object, it is acceptable to get String as the respose is already string.

in the other side, if the returned object actually not Object of String, it will gives you classcastexeption.

to handle this case, it is recommended to check the type of the object before you cast it

like

```
Object returnedObject = req.getResponse();
if(returnedObject instanceof String)
{
// we can cast it now as string
String str = (String) returnedObject;
// use str as string safely now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Here is a breef explanation of casting in Java:

> In summary, type casting in the sense of casting between classes only
>   informs the compiler that a certain object should be treated as of a
>   certain type.  However, whether that object is indeed of that type
>   depends on runtime type information.  Furthermore, type casting only
>   makes sense from a superclass object to a subclass object.  That is if
>   B is a subclass of A and x is declared to be of type A: (A x;), which
>   means that x has static type A, then   B y = (B)x;    is required to
>   type cast x from an A object to a B object.  Type casting in the
>   reverse direction, from subclass to superclass, is implicit:   x = y; 
>   // assuming y has static type B. this is because a B object is ALWAYS
>   an A object. Why is ( B y = (B)x; ) allowed? because an A object COULD
>   BE a B object.
>
> Furthermore, type casting is only allowed between superclass and
>   subclass. If C also extends/implements A, then casting from B to C or
>   C to B will both  generate compiler errors.  B and C will in general
>   each contain information and procedures not found in the other, so one
>   cannot simply "become" the other.

Taken from http://www.cs.hofstra.edu/~cscccl/csc17/casting.java.